# I still can not install Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04

I input the command "sudo service lightdm stop", I still can not install the Nvidia driver NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run. The error information is that I need stop X server.
How can I install the driver?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to install drivers from a `run` file. Install it from Ubuntu repositories or `graphics-drivers` ppa.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add ppa ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html) and install it with apt-get or "Additional drivers".

Answer (score 0):

Vulkan ready nvidia driver : ( NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run )  runs just fine on ubuntu 16.04 as long as your graphics card appears on this list :   https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver

When I installed the driver by downloading directly from nvidia it locked up my machine so I then tried this which worked :

remove all existing nvidia packages :

```
        dpkg -l|grep nvidia

        sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*

        dpkg -l|grep nvidia
```

then add this repo

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

reboot and you will be on nouveau however get into Settings->Software & Updates->Additional Drivers  ... choose Nvidia 367.35 (the highest number)
... reboot again and you can confirm you are now ready to run Vulkan on ubuntu 16.04

```
dpkg -l|grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-367                                  367.35-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.35
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                       367.35-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2                                                       amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             367.35-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Now you can install Vulkan ... afterward this confirms its OK

```
vulkaninfo
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan API Version: 1.0.21

INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_threading.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_core_validation.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_object_tracker.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_image.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_api_dump.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_swapchain.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_unique_objects.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_vktrace_layer.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_parameter_validation.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/other_src/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_screenshot.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/stens/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json, version "1.0.0"

Instance Extensions:
====================
Instance Extensions count = 4
    VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
    VK_KHR_xcb_surface                  : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_xlib_surface                 : extension revision  6
    VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  2


Layers: count = 13
=======
VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading (Google Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.0.21, layer version 1
...
...
...
```